# convert txt to csv not working with big content using java 8

Tags: java, csv, java-8

Hi I want to convert from txt to CSV file. In my txt file I have \t as separator.
So My java code looks as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Path path = Paths.get("D:\\chat-log\\output\\");
        final Path txt = path.resolve("summary_Traders_Violation_Rule2_Conversation.txt");
        final Path csv = path.resolve("Rule2.csv");
        try (
                final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(txt);
                final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(csv, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW))) {
            lines.map((line) -> line.split("\t")).
                    map((line) -> Stream.of(line).collect(Collectors.joining(","))).
                    forEach(pw::println);
        }
    }
```

It creates CSV file with Exception and csv file doesnot contain full data from txt file. only blank values till column 1,2,3 are ok the moment column 4 values starts its throwing exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at XPathEx.TxtToCsv.main(TxtToCsv.java:24)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: check your incoming data

Answer (score 2):

`Files.lines(Path)` opens the file for reading with UTF-8 as the charset, and your file seems to contain some non-UTF-8 data.

Check, which charset you need, and use [`Files.lines(Path path, Charset cs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) instead.